# Cannot get past Login screen in Modx Revo 2.7.0pl

Tags: authentication, modx

My problem: Users don't get further from login screen. They show up as logged-in in the manager log and Whos online, but the login screen just shows an empty login-form after submit login.
*It all worked for several days after last upgrade to 2.7.0.pl, and then suddenly stopped.*

Error log: `(ERROR @ /home/verkejml/public_html/core/model/modx/moduser.class.php : 362) PHP warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active.`

Tried:

- Delete all files in core/cache.
- Delete browser cache and cookies.
- Different browsers and different users with different permissions, up
  to admin.
- Reading all forum questions about the same problem, no luck.

I have one admin user logged in, and I'm super afraid to log out that user, if I'm not able to login again, and therefor can't access the manager again.

My setup:
Modx Revo 2.7.0pl.
Just a few "standard" extras installed, all updated.
PHP 7.0.33

Question: Is there anything I can do without reinstall everything, and by that be forced to log out my only logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the incredibly engaged and knowledgeable problem solver in the Modx community, BobRay:

My (old) settings:

```
session_cookie_path => (blank) 
anonymous_sessions => No
```

Changed to

```
session_cookie_path => / 
anonymous_sessions => Yes
```

Thanks to BobRay for great help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are any problems with MODX 2.7 + PHP 7.* nowadays. 
Here are other possible steps which may help you:

- Disable anonymous_sessions setting and relogin again
- Remove modSessionHandler value for session_handler_class and relogin again

> I have one admin user logged in, and I'm super afraid to log out that user, if I'm not able to login again, and therefor can't access the manager again.

Honestly I don't know how to test without logging out ((